# Django Queryset returns None, but the inner query works correctly

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I've got a QuerySet that's behaving a little strangely.  When I run the `self.get()` section individually and print the results (i.e. `pr`), it correctly returns the PriceRange object.  When I return the same value, it's None.

```
class PriceRangeQuerySet(QuerySet):
    def get_price_range(self, price):
        try:
            pr = self.get(
                    (Q(bottom__isnull = True) | Q(bottom__lt = price)) & \
                    (Q(top__isnull = True) | Q(top__gte = price))
                )
            return pr
        except PriceRange.DoesNotExist:
            mail_admins("Price range not found", 'Price: %d' % price)
        except PriceRange.MultipleObjectsReturned:
            mail_admins("Multiple matching price ranges found", 'Price: %d' % price)
```

Comment: It is weird. .get() should not return None in any case, right?

Comment: Yeah, I'm puzzled.  As far as I can tell, get() is **not** returning None.  When I print the value of 'pr' from within the function, it's fine, but the act of returning the value somehow nullifies it?